# Alternative for Xshell.

Tags: openssh, putty, port-forwarding

Do anyone knows an alternative for xshell? I have checked and the alternatives mentioned are putty, openssh etc. But I require it mainly for port forwarding and for that xshell works perfectly. Is there any way(apart from using wine) to install xshell in ubuntu precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to use xshell in Ubuntu? The standard ssh client that comes with Ubuntu has [all the port forwarding capabilities](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) you probably need.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Thanks also to @devav2. I'm aware of port forwarding capabilities of standard ssh clients. Problem is I have tried with putty, ssh tunneling, pac manageretc. but the connection is intermittent. The connection gets disconnected after sometime. But in xshell, it is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **PAC Manager**. To install check this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/files/) download the .deb file and install it using command `sudo dpkg -i <package.deb>`

**Description grabbed from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/davidtv/)**

> PAC is a Perl/GTK Gnome replacement for SecureCRT/Putty/etc... It
>   provides a GUI to configure SSH/Telnet connections: users, passwords,
>   EXPECT regular expressions, macros, etc. You like 'SSHMenu'? If so,
>   you must check this tool. Just let me know how do you feel about it!